# How can method in Swift with inout parameter be used in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I want

```
func foo(inout stop: Bool) -> Void {
    // ...
}
```

use in my Objective-C part. But it is never generated in Module-Swift.h header. If I mark it with @objc, the

> Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot
>   be represented in Objective-C

error occurs.

Comment: it is saying you can't.

Comment: Any workaround? Or it is just deadend?

Comment: Does `Bool!` instead of `Bool` work?

Comment: you can use mutable pointer which should translate to `BOOL *`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't use an `inout` parameter when bridging with Objective-C, but you can do something similar if you use an `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` (`T` would be `Bool` in your case). It would look something like this:

```
@objc func foo(stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<Bool>) -> Void {
    if stop != nil {
        // Use the .pointee property to get or set the actual value stop points to
        stop.pointee = true
    }
}
```

---

### Example

TestClass.swift:

```
public class TestClass: NSObject {
    @objc func foo(stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<Bool>) -> Void {
        stop.pointee = true
    }
}
```

Objective-C:

```
TestClass *test = [[TestClass alloc] init];
BOOL stop = false;
[test foo:&stop];
// stop is YES here
```

Comment: How do you pass UnsafeMutablePointer from swift to objective-c?

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to what happening with generics, `inout` is not objc-compatible.

One possible workaround is to embed your parameter(s) in a class (which is a reference type, hence passed by pointer and not by value):

```
@objc class MyFuncParams {
    var stop: Bool

    init(stop: Bool) {
        self.stop = stop
    }
}
```

and define the function to accept an instance of that class:

```
func changeParam(params: MyFuncParams) {
    params.stop = true
}
```

Not an elegant way to solve the problem, but what's important is that it should work (never tried myself though).